# .NET Core application with SQL Server database where table names are prefixed C# - dynamic table name

Tags: c#, sql-server, dynamic-sql, prepared-statement

I am wondering whether it is possible and good practice to keep table prefix in config file and use it in each `SqlCommand` query by appending it to actual table name, so two applications with same table structure could use the same database without sharing the data.

As of now all of my `SqlCommand` queries are like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from SomeTable", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader dr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Model _record = new Model();
                    _record.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]);
                    _record.Value = Convert.ToString(dr["Value"]);

                    RecordsList.Add(_record);
                }
            }
        }

        connection.Close();

        return RecordsList;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE SomeTable SET Value = @Value " +
                                              "WHERE ID = @Id;", connection))
    {
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Value", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = _record.Value;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = _record.Id;

        connection.Open();
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

As you can see I use parameters, but it is not possible to use parameters on Table name.

What should be the approach to protect the query from SQL injection if I wanted to add `prefix_` to the beginning of the table name, so the application would talk to the table prefixed with prefixed stored in settings file?

Comment: After reading the question a few times, I guess my question is: do you have a requirement to use the same database between the two applications? It seems like if data security is a concern between the two applications, then it would be more natural to use separate data stores. Otherwise, if you're really set on using one database, then have a method which returns the correct prefix, and concat the table names in a static initializer method into static fields that won't change over the course of the application instance.

Comment: What about validating the resulting string? Is simple regex stripping it down from non alphanumeric characters enough? It might not be a big issue since having access to config file would mean that they already have dB connection string.

Comment: @AndyStagg yeah, writing method to get prefix from config file is not a problem. I could concat it with table name and insert into the query like Select * FROM [“ + concatstring + “] Where..... I am thinking about doing Regex check on that string before

Comment: @AndyStagg yeah, I think keeping these names static over the course of app lifetime is not bad idea. To answer your question, I think some clients might want to install app along with existing application as not everyone can have access to more than 1 dB. And then, some might want to add prefix to add security, but every sql command is already parametrized as I said so there should not be user input possible into the query.

Comment: All comments and answers in this thread considered, I still think multiple databases are a better idea. You could just as easily switch between database with multiple connection strings (one for each application/customer) then switching table names. Concerning your wordpress comment, I would assume that each site gets it's own database on their server, not that each site gets its own tables in a single database.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple utility function to wrap a table name in delimiters, and prevent SQL Injections.  It's a C# implementation of the TSQL [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function:

```
    private static string QuoteName(string identifier)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(identifier.Length + 3, 1024);
        sb.Append('[');
        foreach (var c in identifier)
        {
            if (c == ']')
                sb.Append(']');
            sb.Append(c);
        }
        sb.Append(']');
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

And you would use it like this:

```
var sql = $"UPDATE {QuoteName(SomePrefix + "_" + SomeTable)} SET Value = @Value WHERE ID = @Id;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answers: Is it possible? Yes. Is it a good idea? Not in the vast majority of cases.

If you are considering this kind of trick then it suggests that a better overall design strategy would be appropriate. There are concepts such as owner schema and multi-tenant design which are common and well documented, which provide a much cleaner and platform-supported approach to segregation of data stores.

Tricks such as your prefix idea almost always lead to catastrophic issues over the lifetime of an application unless approached with an elite level of infrastructure design. Even then, some of the best implemented designs often have their issues.

Comment: Yes, I thought it’s not a good idea. I shall read about schemas. The application builds dB structure including tables creation only at configuration time. I must find a way of using different schema for each instance.

Comment: And what about Wordpress, are they not using table prefix on installation?